# I thought the point of iterators was that they *were* their underlying type?

Tags: c++

I have the following

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

enum EMode
{
     a
    ,b
    ,c
};

void doTheThing(const EMode m)
{
    std::cout << "Found mode " << m << std::endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<EMode> modeList;

    modeList.push_back(EMode::a);
    modeList.push_back(EMode::c);

    const auto mode = find_if(modeList.cbegin(), modeList.cend(), [](const EMode m)
    {
        return c == m;
    });

    if(modeList.end() != mode)
    {
        doTheThing(mode);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The problem is that this code will not compile.

I get an error when I call doTheThing(mode);

The error is:

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>'
>   to 'const EMode'

I'm at a loss, because to my knowledge mode should be a vector iterator that should resolve to an EMode when I try to use it to call doTheThing(mode);

What am I missing?

Comment: Iterators are *not* the type, they are closer to *pointers to* the type.

Comment: The point of iterators is to provide a common interface for accessing elements of different containers

Comment: This leads to the 'unusual' situation that you can use both `.` and `->` to select members. `.` will select members of the iterator class, and `->` will select members of the referenced class.

Comment: @M.M -- iterators provide access to elements of **sequences**. Containers are one way of creating sequences, but they are not the only way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterators are not the same type as the underlying data. They *dereference* to that type.

Instead of

```
doTheThing(mode);
```

use

```
doTheThing(*mode);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a vector, iterators are *generalizations* of **pointers** to T.  (That is, they might not be actual pointers, but may be classes that will act as if they were pointers), dereferenced with * and -> like pointers are, incrementable (if forward iterator), pointer arithmetic by arbitrary jumps (if random access iterator), decrementable (if bidirectional), and so on.

```
myVector.push_back(someObject);
auto iter = myVector.begin();
if (*iter == myVector[0]) // will be true unless operator== is weird for T
  ...
```